# Could not convert string to float: 'f' and error relates to local variable

Tags: python

I try to run the program below to get the temperature from the user, then use the temperature to convert to the other scale, then display it in the main function. Converted temperature will be calculated depend on the user choices.

```
def main():
    #Print the menu, and get the user choice.
    print("\nTemperature Conversion")
    print("1. Fahrenheit to Celcius")
    print("2. Celcius to Fahrenheit")
    print("3. Exit")
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice == "1":
        getTemp("f")
        fahr2Celsius("f")
        print("The ", "{0:.0f}".format(fahrenheit),
        "degree fahrenheit is converted to ", "{0:.0f}".format(celsius),
         "Celsius degree.")
    elif choice == "2":
        getTemp("c")
        cels2Fahrenheit("c")
        print("The ", "{0:.2f}".format(celsius), 
        "degree Celsius is converted to ", 
        "{0:.2f}".format(fahrenheit), "Fahrenheit degree.")
    elif choice == "3":
        print("Exit the program.")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid choice.")

#Get the temperature from the user, then assigned it to a variable.
def getTemp(value):
    if value == "f":
        f = float(input("Enter the Fahrenheit degrees: "))
        return f
    elif value == "c":
        c = float(input("Enter the Celsius degrees: ")) 
        return c

#Convert the temperature, then return back the value in an assigned variable.
def fahr2Celsius(fahrenheit):
    celsius = float((float(fahrenheit) - 32) * 5 / 9)
    return celsius


def cels2Fahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = (float((9/5) * float(celsius) + 32))
    return fahrenheit

#Call the main function.
main()
```

And I got the error saying that:

```
could not convert string to float: 'f'
```

I'm not sure what happens, and I also have red marks at the word "fahrenheit"and "celsius" in:

```
print("The ", "{0:.0f}".format(fahrenheit),
        "degree fahrenheit is converted to ", "{0:.0f}".format(celsius),
         "Celsius degree.")
print("The ", "{0:.2f}".format(celsius), 
        "degree Celsius is converted to ", 
        "{0:.2f}".format(fahrenheit), "Fahrenheit degree.")
```

What should I do?

Comment: which line shows the error?

Comment: add the full error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
getTemp("f")
fahr2Celsius("f")
```

You pass `"f"` to `fahr2Celsius` which is expecting a user input value.

I think you meant:

```
fahrenheit = getTemp("f")
celsius= fahr2Celsius(fahrenheit)

...
celsius = getTemp("c")
fahrenheit = cels2Fahrenheit(celsius)
```

Plus, the conversions don't necessarily need conversions to `float`:

```
def fahr2Celsius(fahrenheit):
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9


def cels2Fahrenheit(celsius):
    return ((9/5) * celsius) + 32
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the result of `getTemp("f")` to a variable, and your function `fahr2Celsius` is expecting a float as a string but instead you pass it `"f"` instead of the result of `getTemp("f")`.

A similar error is made for the celsius conversion.

The reason `farhenheit` and `celsius` have squiggly lines under them is because they haven't been defined. Hovering over the squiggly line will tell you the reason fo the squiggle in most editors.